# Removing Last Comma in a For & Foreach Loop

Tags: php, csv

Here's my script

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $compatibilitycount; $i++) {
foreach ($xml->Item->ItemCompatibilityList->Compatibility[$i] as $compatibility ) {
   if ($compatibility->Value != '') {
      $value = $compatibility->Value  . ',';
      echo $value;
   }
}
   echo '<br />';
}
```

which outputs a csv like so

```
2006,Chrysler,Sebring,Touring Sedan 4-Door,2.7L 2700CC 167Cu. In. V6 FLEX DOHC Naturally Aspirated,
2006,Chrysler,Sebring,Touring Sedan 4-Door,2.7L 2700CC 167Cu. In. V6 GAS DOHC Naturally Aspirated,
2006,Chrysler,Sebring,TSi Sedan 4-Door,2.7L 2700CC 167Cu. In. V6 GAS DOHC Naturally Aspirated,
2006,Dodge,Charger,Base Sedan 4-Door,2.7L 2700CC 167Cu. In. V6 GAS DOHC Naturally Aspirated,
```

I am having a tough time removing the trailing comma from each line.

I've looked at past questions tried to use `implode()` `rtrim()` and putting `$value` into an array it just but nothing is working. It is kind of driving me crazy because I'm sure the solution is simple.

My goal is to save the output as a csv (but first am just trying to echo the output normally).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: please show the implode and rtrim you used that did not work

Comment: Why is nobody ever capable of finding PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), hidden away as it is among the [Filesystem functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) section of the PHP Docs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do not display the text immediately. "Cache it" and then display it, but remove the last character either by [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) or [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $compatibilitycount; $i++) {
    $result = '';
    foreach ($xml->Item->ItemCompatibilityList->Compatibility[$i] as $compatibility ) {
       if ($compatibility->Value != '') {
          $result .= $compatibility->Value  . ',';
       }
    }
    echo substr($result, 0, -1) . '<br />';
    // or echo rtrim($result, ',') . '<br />';
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out there are better ways to create a CSV using native PHP functions, but if you still want to go your way here's your code edited a bit to make it working without using `rtrim` or an `array` to store the result:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $compatibilitycount; $i++) {
    $first = true;

    foreach ($xml->Item->ItemCompatibilityList->Compatibility[$i] as $compatibility ) {
        if ($compatibility->Value != '') {
            echo ($first ? '' : ',') . $compatibility->Value;

            $first = false;
        }
    }
}
```